# VideoView sobrepondo outro videoView na TabActivity Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Tenho um `TabActivity` com duas `Tabs`, em ambas tem um `VideoView` (Homem|Mulher). Quando inicio uma das `Tabs` e depois troco para a outra, o vídeo da primeira ainda continua executando por baixo do outro vídeo. Como posso resolver isso?

Segue código que estou utilizando:

TabActivity

```
public class BarraTabActivity extends TabActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("homem").setIndicator("Homem").setContent(new Intent(this, HomemActivity.class)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("mulher").setIndicator("Mulher").setContent(new Intent(this, MulherActivity.class)));
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

Activity Homem

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homem);

    String path = "www.exemplo.com";

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vwHomem);
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
}
```

Activity Mulher

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mulher);

    String path = "www.exemplo.com";

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vwMulher);
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
}
```

Layout (Para Homem ou Mulher é igual, só mudam o nomes)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vwHomem" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando as tabs `Homem` ou `Mulher` forem criadas, é bom verificar se o outro vídeo não pertencente a ela está sendo executado, se sim, pausar ele e deixar invisível.

> Woman Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mulher);

    String path = "www.exemplo.com";

    vwMen   = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vwMulher);
    vwWoman = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vwHomem);

    // setMediaController, setVideoUri e RequestFocus, mas ainda não inicie-o.
}

@Override
protected void onResume (){
    super.onResume();

    if(vwMen.isPlaying()) {
        vwMen.pause();
        vwMen.suspend();
        vwMen.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        vwWoman.start();

    } else vwWoman.start();
}
```

Faça isso nas duas `activity`, sempre verificando se um outro vídeo está sendo executado.

Answer (score 0):

Tente chamar o método pause no método onPause da Activity.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition(); 
    videoView.pause();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    videoView.seekTo(stopPosition);
    videoView.start();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas não funcionou, o vídeo continua um por cima do outro, mesmo estando em activitys diferentes.